# How to align (remove white space between) two objects in Adobe XD?

Tags: alignment, adobe-xd

I'm new to Adobe XD. At the moment I'm trying to make a card. For that I made a box and I want to add a line to it. My problem is when I try to align that line to the box, it doesnt align.

Here are two screenshots:

First try:
[image]

When I try to move it to the left:
[image]

But I want the line to align to the white box.

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice sometimes when things are not aligning against each other that one of the objects may be `.5`on the x or y axis compared to the other object you're working with.

[image]

Simply remove the extra `.5` from axis and your items should align.

Answer (score 0):

In XD, lines will snap to other objects more cleanly if you change the end caps to "Projecting" (aka square caps):

[image: XD end-cap choices]

This will give you perfectly aligned intersections just by using the regular snapping when drawing/resizing/moving lines, without having to manually change the X/Y values at all:

[image: line perfectly snapped to edge of artboard]